# Default parameter for MockedObject.Verify()

Tags: moq

I have a mocked object and am verifying some things called. But wanted to know what the default parameter is for `MockedObject.Verify(thingToBeVerified)`?

Is it Times.Zero, Times.Once, or even Times.AtLeastOnce?

I am using Moq 4.2 in NUnit 2.6.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Times.AtLeastOnce() is the default

Comment: Can I ask where you got this answer from? I haven't been able to find anything anywhere.

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/Mock.Generic.cs#L340) is a pretty good place to look :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think to look there. That completely answers my question.